# Win32: Returning a minimized and hidden window to top

Tags: c, windows, winapi, system-tray

I'm unable to restore a window after "minimizing" a window to tray, by doing this in wndproc:

```
case WM_SIZE:
  if (wparam==SIZE_MINIMIZED) {
    ShowWindow(hwnd,SW_HIDE);
  }
  break;
```

The tray message handler looks like this:

```
case TRAY_ICON_MESSAGE:
  switch(lparam) {
  case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
    BringWindowToTop(hwnd);
    SetFocus(hwnd);
    break;
  // ...
```

The window does re-appear, but is always hidden beneath other windows and doesn't come to the top. Neither SetFocus() nor BringWindowToTop() appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you have a look if the functions return any errors?

You could also have a look at [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (::IsIconic(hwnd))  
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);  

::SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);  
::BringWindowToTop(hwnd);
```

Answer (score -1):

Never use SetForeground.

See Msdn remarks.

Comment: Which ones? The documentation seems to suggest it is perfectly ok to use in certain circumstances